# AS3 drawing movement path for object

Tags: actionscript-3, multi-touch

So I want to create a game for a touch table and I am looking for a code that creates a path by drawing it. I want it for now with a mouse_down event so if anyone could help me out or tell me if it's possible that would be great. I have no code to show what I have for the path, But I am now using the move to mouse position click event.

Well I hope I gave you peeps enough information on this matter.

Greeting,

Angelo

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and I am sure a quick Google would show many ways to do it.

You can use the [Graphics API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html) to draw lines. You might want to store the mouse position on mouse move, and draw a line from the previous position to the current position on move.

You will probably mostly want the moveTo and lineTo functions.